# I'm trying to build a to-do-list application in Objective C but coming up short

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm getting this error: `-[NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: attempt to insert nil`

Here is the .m file:

```
/*
 IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
 IBOutlet NSTabView *tableView;
 IBOutlet NSButton *button;
 NSMutableArray *myArray;
 */

#import "AppController.h"


@implementation AppController


-(IBAction)addNewItem:(id)sender
{
    myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] init];
    [tableView setDataSource:self];
    [textField stringValue];
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
    string = [textField stringValue];



    [myArray addObject:string];
    NSLog(@"%d",[myArray count]);
    NSLog(@"%@",string);

}

- (int)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
{
    return [myArray count];
}
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn
            row:(int)rowIndex
{
    //NSString *data = [myArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
    return [myArray objectAtIndex:rowIndex];
}




@end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] init];
string = [textField stringValue];
[myArray addObject:string];
```

First off, you have a memory leak, since you `alloc` and `init` an empty `NSString`, but then immediately lose the reference to it by assigning in the `textField`'s `stringValue`.

Also, if the textField doesn't have a string in it, then `stringValue` will return `nil` and cause your `addObject:` message to fail, since you can't invoke it with `nil` as a parameter.

In addition, your first couple lines (`tableView = [[NSTableView alloc] init]; [textField stringValue];`) just don't make sense.  You specified that you have an `IBOutlet` to the tableview, so why are you creating a new one?  Since you're assigning the new tableview into your instance variable, you're leaking the `IBOutlet` and then releaking a tableview every time this method is invoked.  Also, you're invoking `stringValue` and totally ignoring the return value.

I recommend reading up a bit more about `IBOutlets` and how to use them in your code.  Here are a couple links:  [Link 1](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/IB_UserGuide/CodeIntegration/CodeIntegration.html), [Link 2](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html)